# How can I get the most recent result from a table with a column that has multiple of the same values

Tags: mysql, post, duplicates

I'm trying to get make my table get **only 1** of the results that I have in the table. My table stores a posted_by column that allows more than 1 user to post more than once. So, my posted_by column has multiple of the username Chowderrunnah because that user has posted more than once. I only want to display one of the results so each user can be clicked on in the table instead of displaying many of the same user. (I'm trying to create a support ticket system if you're wondering why).

At the moment, my table is getting all the results from my table, even duplicates with the same posted_by (username). I only want it to display one result if there are more than 1 of the same posted by (username).

At the moment, my code is only the minimum -

```
SELECT * from support WHERE last_post_by != 'Admin'
```

Help is much appreciated.

***Edit***

Here is the table I'm using [image: Database]

Here is my support ticket system

[image]

Comment: Can you update your query with a sample data along with what your expected output is?  I'm thinking that `SELECT DISTINCT` or using `GROUP BY` might be what you want, but it is not clear.

Comment: What about using  **GROUP BY** ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh sorry. I thought I made it very clear. But my output, I want it to fetch only 1 of the rows from my table where the column posted_by is used more than once. Obviously, when there is only 1 result with the username username for posted_by, it's not needed, but I want it because there is going to be more than 1 posted_by that is matched because it's their username's for my support ticket system.

Comment: Please provide sample data in your table and desired outcome. That should clarify your question to us.

Comment: Use bit or 0/1 as status. Don't use string or varchars. You are just showing the snapshot. Please try to share sample output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Query fixed my problem :)

```
SELECT * from support WHERE last_post_by != 'Admin' GROUP BY posted_by
```

Using GROUP BY allowed me to only display one of the duplicate posted_by results.